# Xamarin Android - sorting iBeacon iCollection causes exception

Tags: android, sorting, xamarin, ibeacon, icollection

I'm trying to sort an iCollection of iBeacon objects, but as soon as the code runs it throws an exception. The code i'm trying to run is as follows. It works fine without any ordering or sorting, but i need to be able to sort the collection on proximity, as shown (with lowest proximity first i.e proximity being equal to 1):

```
async void RangingBeaconsInRegion(object sender, RangeEventArgs e)
   {

     if (e.Beacons.Count > 0) 
      {
        var orderedBeacons = e.Beacons.OrderBy(b => b.Proximity); //this causes the problem

      foreach (var beacon1 in orderedBeacons) 
       {
          //do all my stuff here on my ordered beacons
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.ArgumentException: 'jmethod' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
[mono] Parameter name: jmethod
[mono]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Android.Runtime.JavaCollection`1[RadiusNetworks.IBeaconAndroid.IBeacon].CopyTo (RadiusNetworks.IBeaconAndroid.IBeacon[] array, Int32 array_index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[IBeacon] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Linq.QuickSort`1[RadiusNetworks.IBeaconAndroid.IBeacon]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Linq.SortContext`1 context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Linq.QuickSort`1+<Sort>c__Iterator0[RadiusNetworks.IBeaconAndroid.IBeacon].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any ideas how i can get the collection ordered correctly please?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in the AltBeacon library. I think it's related to the transfer of type from a JavaCollection to a .NET ICollection, but I'm still looking.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Very bizarre. Either a Xamarin bug or a race condition in the AltBeacon library I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Let me know how it goes.

```
var allBeacons = new List<Beacon>();

foreach(var b in e.Beacons)
{
    allBeacons.Add(b);
}

var orderedBeacons = allBeacons.OrderBy(b => b.Proximity);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Good stuff, perfect!